# Как задать функцию в Wolfram mathematica?

Tags: mathematica

Как задать функцию

```
F(x) = 2x^2-2x-2 при x<=2
F(x) = sqrt(x-1) при x=2
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).